# Any plans for sign-in using Persona?

Tags: feature-request

Any plans to implement sign-in using [Mozilla's Persona project](https://login.persona.org/)?  My understanding is that this project is more privacy-friendly than signing in with Google or Facebook.

Comment: Looks like an OpenID clone.  Stack Exchange uses OpenID, as does Google and Facebook, so you don't have to use them; you can use any OpenID provider you want.

Comment: Here's a [comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Persona/FAQ). My limited understanding is that privacy (and potential native-browser integration?) are advantages over OpenID, but I'm definitely not an expert.

Comment: A [counter-opinion](http://www.opine.me/mozilla-persona-browserid-is-a-step-in-the-wrong-direction/).

Comment: Hm, yeah, and a [reply](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4259897).  It sounds like it is still not fully-baked.  Although the discussion is a little old.

Comment: I am a big fan of Persona, think it's a large improvement over OpenID, and have objections to many of the criticisms, but sadly that is all moot: [Mozilla has stopped non-maintenance work on Persona](http://identity.mozilla.com/post/78873831485/transitioning-persona-to-community-ownership), and has essentially given up on it after it failed to gather wide adoption. I don't think that it would be worth the effort for Stack Exchange to adopt it as this point.

Comment: @Jeremy Banks Thanks, I didn't realize that was the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Persona says:

> On November 30th, 2016, Mozilla **shut down** the persona.org services. Persona.org and related domains will soon be taken offline. [emphasis mine]

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate on MSE that has been declined: [Implement Mozilla Persona for login?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148644/implement-mozilla-persona-for-login)

> We support OpenID logins because it is a widely adopted standard with a significant number of providers.
>
> We support Facebook logins via OAuth2.0 (but did not via Facebook Connect), as OAuth2.0 is more or less a standard with a large number of users behind it.  If/When Twitter supports OAuth2.0, we'll probably support it as well.
>
> BrowserID isn't nearly prevalent enough to warrant consideration at this point.

You could start a bounty on that question with **Current answers are outdated** as the reason.